# pacman option to search for packages that own a file

Tags: files, arch-linux, package-management, pacman

What is the pacman option to search for a package that owns a file? Like `dpkg -S` in Debian-based distros.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is `pacman -Qo <filename>`.

#### Example

```
% pacman -Qo x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-pkg-config
/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-pkg-config is owned by pkgconf 1.6.3-1
```

From [pacman(8)](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html):

> Query Options (apply to **-Q**)
>
> **-o, --owns** <file>
>
> Search for packages that own the specified file(s). The path can be relative or absolute, and one or more files can be specified.

Comment: Perfect, the only answer that is useful.

Comment: The files I have are *not* owned by any package because they arrived by some nefarious means. I'd like to find out who is *supposed* to own them, so I can properly `pacman -S` those packages. `-Qo` only reports "error: No package owns". I'm therefore looking at @mabalenk's answer.

Answer (score 2):

From [Pacman/Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta#Querying_specific_packages) (adapted from a table):

> Query the package which provides FILE
>
> - Arch: `pacman -Qo`
> - Debian/Ubuntu: `dpkg -S` / `dlocate`

As shown above (and as its name implies), the page presents ways to perform
certain actions in `pacman` and their equivalents in other package managers, so
it might be worth checking out when coming from other distributions.

Comment: Perfect, the only answer that is useful.

Answer (score 2):

To search for a remote package (a package not installed on the system) use:

```
pacman -F <filename>
```

For example,

```
pacman -F omp-tools.h
```

This command will give you the remote package name.

Comment: Trying this because I have files that exist but have not been installed by `pacman`. I'm getting: `warning: database file for 'core' does not exist (use '-Fy' to download)` and the same message for `extra` instead of `core`.